# Google Analytics not displaying accurate data for all pages report

Tags: google-analytics

I am tracking analytics through a Google Analytics - Universal Analytics tag implemented through GTM.

I've noticed recently that there may have been an issue with the setup of this which has resulted in a large amount of data missing (a few months worth) - specifically there is a lack of data in the site content > all pages report. Some data was recorded in June 2018 before recording appears to have stopped, however it appears this data is incorrect with very high page readings that are not reflected by the timeline in the audience overview report.

What's strange is that goals have still been recorded, including form submission and calls (these were also set up through GTM), also the audience overview has recorded data for the last six months.

I have added the analytics tag again making sure to have the correct property ID and have verified that it is firing via preview mode and via the real-time report in Analytics.

I'm confused how sessions and goals have been recorded if analytics may have been incorrectly installed and what may have occurred for there to be a black hole in the data?

Answer (score 0):

If there is a lack of data in the **site content** report it means that on some pages from your site, either GTM is not firing (thus not firing GA) or there are some filters in your GA trigger in GTM which do not load the tag on all pages.

If you can provide some URL's which you think should be in the **site content** report, but are missing, we can check how  GA is installed.

Comment: Thanks for the response,

Comment: Thanks for the response, after installing the GA tag through GTM i've set it to trigger on all page views - unfortunately i'm not sure what it was set to previously, or if it was even correctly installed. Checking GA again today, it appears to be working correctly after adding the tag yesterday (there is now data in the site content report), however, i'm still wondering why the other reports are showing data if GA may have not been on the site at all? Is this a reporting error? This is the website: https://mylestones.org.au/. Thanks again for the help

Comment: Just to add - it's showing audience data and goal data for the last approx. 6 months.